# How to fix issue with filtering internal traffic in comparison - GA4

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

Our website is set up with GA4 via the Global Site Tag method, and we have been looking into excluding internal traffic. We also have a Universal Analytics property with a view which excludes internal traffic (this has been tested and is working).

I have followed the steps in defining internal traffic in GA4 through the web steam and then creating a data filter to exclude the specified IP - this is currently in testing mode. When looking at the 'Realtime' report I have added a comparison using the following conditions:

Exclude / Test data filter name / Internal Traffic

At first this did appear to work as the Realtime report was showing a reduced number of users in the Internal Traffic comparison compared to All Users. After a few days this changed and we have since been seeing exactly the same figure for both comparisons, despite the fact that some of these users should have been recorded as internal.

Our IP is static and we have used the same one as we did for our Universal Analytics property, so we are at a bit of a loss as to why we have been experiencing problem with our GA4 property. I have also looked at other reports within GA4, adding a secondary dimension using the Internal Traffic filter - within these reports we do have events marked as internal, so I would imagine that this means that the filter *is* identifying internal traffic. In addition to this, I have viewed our website using the 'inspect' feature within Chrome - looking at Network / Payload / Query String Parameters which shows 'tt' (traffic type) as internal whilst on a device with the internal IP address.

If anyone could offer some insight as to why the filter isn't working when adding a comparison this would be most helpful - thank you!